# javafx webview other country language support

Tags: java

i was trying to make a web page and accessible using javafx web view but javafx web view didn't support my local language. am using Amharic language and javafx web view just display small rectangles so any one who know how can i make it to support my language pleas help me.

Comment: Does your system support unicode fonts?

Comment: yes it works on other browsers but not javafx webview.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Make sure you set the correct font.

For example, in your .fxml file:

`<Text layoutX="51.0" layoutY="69.0" strokeWidth="0.0" text="ኢትዮጵያ ኩሪ" > <font><Font name="Nyala" size="30"/> </font> </Text>`